# How to calculate predicted values using glmmTMB?

Tags: r, predict, glmmtmb, glmm

I'm trying to check if bees differing in size can affect pollen deposition over 20 sequential visits. As a response variable, I have the number of pollen grains; as predictors, I have the sequence of 20 flowers. Because the amount of pollen received depends on the previous visitation, I added the round of the experiment as a random variable.

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(dplyr)

# Creating a similar dataset
ID <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5",
        "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5",
        "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5",
        "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5")

sequence <- c(1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5)

round <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(2, 5))

number <- sample(1:100, 20, replace = TRUE)

bee <- c(rep("bee1", 10), rep("bee2", 10))

# Dataframe
test <- data.frame(ID, sequence, round, number, bee)

# Changing variables
test <- test |> 
  mutate(ID = as.factor(ID),
         #sequence = as.factor(sequence),
         round = as.factor(round),
         bee = as.factor(bee))

# Filter for one bee
bee1 <- test |> 
  filter(bee == "bee1")

# Model
bee1_nb <- glmmTMB(number ~ sequence + (1|round), family = "nbinom1",
                              data = bee1)

# Sequence for predict
sequence <- 1:5

# Predict
predict_bee1 <- predict(bee1_nb, list(sequence=sequence),type="response")
```

I'm trying to predict values from the negative binomial generalized mixed-effect model, but it's not working.

I tried to model the data using `lme4` and `glmmTMB`, but for some reason, when I add the random factor, it gives me an error. Even without the random variable, my curve is really weird.

Technically, the sequence should be a factor and not numerical, but I'm not sure if I can use `predict` for factors.

I tried `ggeffects` and `ggpredict`, but I want to add the information for the two bees in the same figure, like this one:

[image: like this one]

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a value for all of the variables in your model, including random-effects grouping variables (i.e, `round`). If you specify `round = NA`, you'll get population-level predictions (i.e. not specific to any particular round).

```r
predict_bee1 <- predict(bee1_nb,
                        newdata = data.frame(sequence, round = NA),
                        type="response")
```

(This limitation will be removed in the next release of the package, see https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/923)